# Battleships in Haskell (beginner)

Tags: haskell

we are supposed to write a function that returns the game area after a bomb was droped

`bombOn x y field -> field(bombed)`, a field looks like this:

```
fieldA :: Int -> Int -> Int
fieldA 1 1 = 0
fieldA 1 2 = 1
fieldA 1 3 = 0
fieldA 2 1 = 2
fieldA 2 2 = 0
fieldA 2 3 = 0
fieldA 3 1 = 1
fieldA 3 2 = 0
fieldA 3 3 = 2
fieldA _ _ = -1
```

my Idea was this:

```
bombOn x y field = if field x y == 0 then field else let field x y = 0 in field
```

but this obviously doesn't work because my return (the part after the in) is false, and now the question how do i now return the **whole field** with an exchanged value?

it would be easy with a list of lists or some differently formated field but with this I have no clue thx.

Comment: `let field x y = 0 in field`...? So you want to return a function?

Comment: I have to return the field as a whole after the change was made

Comment: But functions in Haskell have no "memory": you can not "update" pure functions. You probably want to use some sort of state monad.

Comment: It could also be a new type containing a list of key and values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're using a higher-order encoding: a field is represented as a function. Let me define some type synonyms to clarify this a little:

```
type Coords = (Int, Int)
type Field = Coords -> Int

fieldA :: Field
fieldA (1, 1) = 0
fieldA (1, 2) = 1
fieldA (1, 3) = 0
fieldA (2, 1) = 2
fieldA (2, 2) = 0
fieldA (2, 3) = 0
fieldA (3, 1) = 1
fieldA (3, 2) = 0
fieldA (3, 3) = 2
fieldA _ = -1
```

(I've adjusted `fieldA` to take a tuple of arguments, rather than two curried arguments. I think this makes it easier to see which `Int`s are which.)

What does it mean to update a function? It means creating a new function which differs from the old function at some of its arguments. In this instance we want to make a new function which returns `0` at the bombed spot, but delegates to the old field in all other cases.

```
bombAt :: Coords -> Field -> Field
bombAt bombCoords oldField = \coords ->
    if coords == bombCoords
    then 0
    else oldField coords
```

You can clean up this definition slightly by replacing the lambda with a plain old parameter and using guard clauses instead of `if`.

```
bombAt :: Coords -> Field -> Field
bombAt bombCoords oldField coords
    | bombCoords == coords = 0
    | otherwise            = oldField coords
```

Hopefully you can see how to adjust this to fit the slightly different (un-tupled) type you were given in the exercise.